# How can I include an angular module in an existing module?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, pagination, umbraco7

So I've defined a custom section in Umbraco 7:

```
namespace NZ_Realty_Ltd.CRM
{
    [Application("crm", "CRM", "trayuser", 8)]
    public class CrmSection : IApplication { }
}
```

It shows up, no worries here. But it needs a view and controller. So I made a start on the controller:

```
angular.module("umbraco").controller("CrmController",
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('backoffice/crm/ContactApi/GetAll').success(function (data) {
            $scope.contacts = data;
        });
    });
```

Again, no problem. My data is being read from a C# CRUD api and being sent back to the view. But I want to paginate these results. So I'm trying to use this custom directive to do it: https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

Here's my html view:

```
<div ng-controller="CrmController">

    <umb-pane>
        <p>Page {{currentPage}} / {{totalPages}}</p>
        <p>Showing {{pageSize}} items per page:</p>

        <ul class="contacts">
            <li dir-paginate="contact in contacts | itemsPerPage: 10">
                <span>{{contact.name}}</span>
                <p>{{contact.bio}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
    </umb-pane>

</div>
```

The problem is none of these expressions are showing up (they are all blank). I've missed the step of how to include the pagination module. Actually I've been stuck on it for hours. I've tried everything from:

```
angular.module("umbraco", ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']).controller("CrmController",
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('backoffice/crm/ContactApi/GetAll').success(function (data) {
            $scope.contacts = data;
        });
    });
```

... To just including the directive javascript file from `<script>` tags. But I really have no idea what I'm doing and don't understand the module syntax well enough (I've read through the pagination demo so many times but it just seems SO different to working with the umbraco angularjs app). I saw in the docs that including the second parameter means you're making a new module. But what is the relevance of the information inside the [] on the second parameter? And why would I be creating a new module? Can't I just include the existing directive?

EDIT: This is the closest in my mind to what should work. But I get no contacts listed and no pagination controls showing. My idea with it is to load the pagination module (and thus directive), and then create my controller as normal to avoid conflicts and load order stuff, but also adding default values in the controller as in the example here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview

```
angular.module("angularUtils.directives.dirPagination");
angular.module("umbraco").controller("CrmController",
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('backoffice/crm/ContactApi/GetAll').success(function (data) {
            $scope.contacts = data;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.pageSize = 10;
        });
    });
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are loading the dirPagination.js file? 

  `assetsService.loadJs("/App_Plugins/PaginationEditor/Js/dirPagination.js", $scope }).then(function(){
           //this code executes when the script is done loading
    });`

You can find out more here: http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/api/umbraco.services.assetsService

Comment: Yes, I put it in package.manifest which I then confirmed umbraco is loading it in the correct order on the html page (actually pre-loading all scripts in a single js file).

Answer (score 1):

You could add this before your controller starts:

```
app.requires.push('angularUtils.directives.dirPagination');
```

Read more at:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-7/developing-umbraco-7-packages/47905-Including-an-angular-module